# Comparar elementos de una multilista para calcular un promedio en Python

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Dada una multilista de este estilo, siendo `lista[0]` una lista de referencia:

```
lista = [["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"], ["ABC", "JHK", "GHI"], ["ABC", "DEF", "LMN"]]
```

Y una lista que contiene letras agrupadas de a tres:

```
caracteres = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JHK", "LMN"]
```

Asimismo defino el grado de conservación como el cociente entre el número de veces que un determinado componente de `caracteres` se conservó, y el número total de letras agrupadas de a tres analizadas.

Debo calcular el grado de conservación de cada componente de caracteres. Por ejemplo, comparar los elementos `lista[0][0]`, `lista[1][0]` y `lista[2][0]`, y ver cuántas veces se conservó la secuencia de caracteres ABC. En este caso, el grado de conservación es 1 ya que ABC aparece 3 veces en un total de 3. Procedo de la misma forma para `lista[0][1]`, `lista[1][1]` y `lista[2][1]`, y en este caso el grado de conservación de DEF en esa posición es 0.66 siguiendo el mismo razonamiento del punto anterior. En términos generales debo hacer una iteración a lo largo del primer elemento de `lista`, mientras el segundo permanece fijo, y repetir el proceso para todos los segundos elementos de `lista` .

¿Cómo podría automatizar este cálculo? Este ejemplo es una simplificación de las listas reales con las que estoy trabajando, las cuales cuentan con decenas de miles de cadenas de caracteres.

**EDIT 1: no he agregado algún código mostrando qué intenté hacer porque la verdad es que no sé cómo resolverlo. Soy nuevo en programación y no conozco formas de resolver este problema al menos de forma eficiente.**

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, las preguntas del tipo "tengo esto y no se que hacer" sin haber intentado algo previamente no son bien recibidas, si haz intentado algo por favor agrega el código.

Comment: Hola, gracias por darme la bienvenida. Esto que menciono en la publicación es solamente una parte pequeña de un script mucho más grande, soy novato en la programación y hay cosas que desconozco, no sé cómo resolver este problema y por eso pido una sugerencia. No estoy pidiendo que trabajen gratis por mí.

Comment: Ok te voy a guiar, para poder comparar las cadenas necesitas acceder al eoemto,¿cómo haces eso? Con un ciclo for, en el caso de `lista` serán 2 ciclos ya que es una lista anidada.  Podrás hacer eso?